# best choice of words in requesting a reply to an email: zusenden, mitteilen

Tags: translation, word-usage, word-choice

I need to add a sentence to a letter that has already been translated into German, to say that the recipient of the letter can send his/her evaluation (opinion) either by email or on our website.

My question is whether the verbs in my tentative translation below are the most idiomatic:

> Sie können mir Ihre Meinung per Email zusenden oder sie hier mitteilen: [LINK]

Comment: Looks good. Just make sure "Meinung" is the word you want to use.

Comment: An opinion based evaluation would be Bewertung/Beurteilung, whereas an objective evaluation would be Auswertung. Could you add the word in your native language?

Comment: @Carlster - thanks.  This particular letter asks for a quick opinion (necessarily subjective) on a paper submitted to a journal.  The previous paragraph says "... wäre ich Ihnen sehr dankbar, wenn Sie mir kurz Ihre Meinung über das Manuskript mitteilen können." Unless you think Meinung is inappropriate, I'll stick with it.

Comment: In this case, Meinung is just fine.

Comment: Thanks again.  I'm new to language stackexchanges; is it customary to leave such questions up, or are they too trivial?

Comment: Well, I wasn't sure if your question has quite the right format for this site, so I chose to comment instead of answering.

Comment: You can read about how to ask questions [here](http://german.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: I don't think this question is appropriate for this site. Our partner site ELL has the "we're not a proofreading-service" close-vote, which I'm missing on this site. You should ask that kind of questions in chat (though you haven't enough rep yet). Alternatively, you can address a single issue which causes you trouble. As it stands now, it's way too unspecific. E.g. I can't see what part of the sentence you might be unsure about. Word-choice? Sentence structure? Grammaticality? Just to give you some ideas. I'm going to vote for close anyway.

Comment: @Em1 Thanks for the feedback.  I deleted the question then undeleted it and modified it, hoping it fits the bill now. ( I see many questions about translation and I would not have needed to ask the question if my search on the site had come up with a previous question about these words.)

Comment: Yeah. Many questions about translations. Not off-topic per se, but most of them are–well, let's say–not that good. And you've just said it: Such translations requests are rarely of any help for future visitors. I've retracted my close-vote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Zusenden* is composed of the prefix *zu*, in the sense of *to*(direction), and the verb *senden*, which means *to send*. So, the compound conveys the idea of "to send something to someone".
An Email is obviously an object that you can send (to someone); thus, it fits in context quite well. Another word you could take is *zuschicken*. There's no difference at all<sup>1</sup>.

*Mitteilen* is a compound of the prefix *mit* and the verb *teilen*(*to share*). The compound communicates that you "share information with someone". Possible translations: *to tell*, *to inform*.
An opinion is clearly something you can tell someone; hence, works well again. Another word you could take is *sagen*(*to say*, e.g. "Sagen Sie uns Ihre Meinung"), but in your sentence I'd go with *mitteilen* for sure (sounds a bit more formally and more politely).

Summary: Your sentence is perfectly well.

---

<sup>1</sup> Note that *senden* and *schicken* (without the prefix) are much broader in meaning and are only synonymous in the sense of *to send*.